# CGRect not being set

Tags: cgrect

This seems like a simple issue I'm missing but I obviously can't see it. I'm just trying to adjust one value on a `frame`, so I'm copying my view frames like so:

```
CGRect titleFrame = titleToolbar.frame;
CGRect addressFrame = addressToolbar.frame;
CGRect toolbarFrame = toolbar.frame;
CGRect webFrame = self.view.bounds;

NSLog(@"addressToolbar.frame.size.height = %f",addressToolbar.frame.size.height);
NSLog(@"addressFrame.size.height = %f",addressFrame.size.height);
```

But it's logging out to:

```
2014-02-14 17:28:33:846 Lexly[5282:2571] - addressToolbar.frame.size.height = 44.000000
2014-02-14 17:28:33:847 Lexly[5282:2571] - addressFrame.size.height = 0.000000
```

Why is `addressFrame.size.height` logging out to 0 when `addressToolbar.frame.size.height` is logging to 44?

---

EDIT

`addressToolbar` gets set here, which is called in `viewDidLoad` of a `UIViewController`. It's a `UIView` as you can see. I've included every reference to `addressToolbar` in this method, but left out the initialization of other views:

```
- (void)setupView {

//////////////////////
// Setup view
CGRect viewFrame = self.view.bounds;

CGFloat navBarHeight = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
CGFloat statusBarHeight = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;
addressToolbar = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, navBarHeight + statusBarHeight, 320, 44)];


...

[addressToolbar addSubview:urlField];
[addressToolbar addSubview:loadingIndicator];

...

[self.view addSubview:addressToolbar];


}
```

`addressToolbar`'s height get logged to `44.0f` after creation.

Comment: What do you mean you can't set anything? Can you show how you're trying to do that?

Comment: @0x7fffffff Sorry, that was a bad question at the end. I changed it to be more clear.

Comment: No problem. Can you show how you're creating `addressToolbar` and setting its frame?

Comment: You got to set .frame.size.height. Also, use NSStringFromCGRect for logging rects, more readable and they are nice.

Comment: So I was modifying an open-source library and using their conventions but I did a messy job and got confused. There were a few errors, and this was really just a crappy question. Not sure what the etiquette is - whether I should just delete it or not.